# Retrieve property from classpath inside POM

Tags: maven-2, resources, properties, maven

For my current project I want to integrate a maven plug-in for database migrations. For this plug-in to work, however, I have to obtain the database settings inside my POM. My database settings are currently placed inside a hibernate.properties file, positioned in a directory that is marked as maven resource. For a variety of reasons I do not want to duplicate my database configurations in both the pom and hibernate.properties.

I'm aware that maven offers a "filtering" ability which makes it possible to specify the database settings as property inside my POM, and reference them inside my `hibernate.properties` as `${property_name}`. But as I'm using multiple maven profiles, with different property resources, this is not a suitable solution. Instead I'd like my database configurations to be loaded from a property file inside my classpath (e.g. `classpath:hibernate.properties`), and use these properties in my migration plug-in configuration.

I have already tried the org.codehaus.mojo » properties-maven-plugin, but this plug-in only accepts absolute locations. Is there a plug-in which can scan all my maven resources for a certain property?

Comment: This borders on a "git'r'done" shortcut and doesn't answer your question, but would it be too much to just pass the property you need in as -Dprop=value to your `mvn` invocation?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an absolute path, use `${basedir}/your/relative/path/here/...`. [`${basedir}`](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide) expands to the absolute path of the directory of the current `pom.xml`.

Comment: my property files are located over x amount of (mvn) resources. i cannot just say ${basedir}/my_dir, because my_dir can vary per profile on which i run my mvn project.

Comment: So? Define a property per profile and use ${basedir} in it to build the path.